# jxta.org, where is it?

Tags: p2p, jxta

There was many projects inside "jxta.org", where are those ? Is it moved to some other place ?

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Networking/jxta/

I am very much in need of many of those open source project. Can some one help me find those please ?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle/Sun migrated Java.net to the Kenai infrastructure recently. The owners of the projects on jxta.org where notified and if they wanted to migrate their projects, they had to make an explicit request.

Regarding JXTA, the Oracle/Sun representative on the JXTA board decided to migrate a sub-set, which is available at http://java.net/projects/jxta/. I don't think the remaining projects have been migrated (or they should still be Google accessible). You may contact the 'new' Java.net administrators for more information.

Comment: The project examples you are searching are obsolete (2.5 and 2.4.1), because new releases of JXTA have been made available from http://jxse.kenai.com/ (2.6 & 2.7). You can find examples in the Practical JXTA II book available online for reading at Scribd. If you have not checked it, I would advise you to try it.